# Simple form Question mark next to label, to display bootstrap tooltip during hover or click - Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Using the Simple Form gem and bootstrap, I'm trying to figure out a way - using Ruby - to add a tooltip next to a form label in the form of a question mark, that displays the tip on hover or click. I'm struggling to find any relevant information to help.

What would I need to add to the standard form input below? I've tried a variety of things but nothing seems close.

```
<%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number" %>
```

When I try the following, the input field isn't shown:

```
<%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number" do %>
    <span data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</span>
<% end %>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could add

```
<span data-toggle='tooltip' title='<%= @your_tooltip_content %>'>?</span>
```

anywhere you need it. For example :

```
<%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number"%>
<span data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</span>
```

EDIT:

This is the best I could do to display `?` with tooltip on the same line :

```
  <%= f.input :phone, label_html: { "data-tooltip" => true, :class => "has-tip", :title => "We need your phone number because..."} %>
```

In your CSS (e.g. `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`), you can add :

```
.has-tip:after{
  font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
  content: " \e085";
  color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

Comment: I've tried using this like the following:

    <%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number" do %>
            <span data-toggle='tooltip' title='We need your phone number because...'>?</span>
        <% end %>

But it makes the form input field disappear, any idea's?

Comment: Don't put it inside a block.

Comment: The only problem with that is it put's the "?" underneath the input field - rather than next to the label which is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: OK, I will need it to be clickable and to appear quicker on hover (seems to be taking a few seconds) so I'll need to work on it, but get's me started. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

[image: phone field with tooltip]

Based off the bootstrap helpers mentioned in the simple_form wiki, with the following, I was able to simply add a tooltip like so:

```
<%= f.input :phone, placeholder: "Phone Number", tooltip: 'We need your phone number because...' %>
```

I just needed to add the tooltip component below:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form_components.rb:
module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Tooltips
      def tooltip(wrapper_options = nil)
        @tooltip ||= begin
          content = tooltip_text
          options[:tooltip_html] ||= {}
          options[:tooltip_html][:title] = content
          options[:tooltip_html]['data-toggle'] = 'tooltip'
          options[:tooltip_html]['data-placement'] = tooltip_position
          options[:tooltip_html]['tabindex'] = '0'

          content ? '' : nil
        end
      end

      def tooltip_text
        tooltip = options[:tooltip]
        if tooltip.is_a?(String)
          html_escape(tooltip)
        elsif tooltip.is_a?(Array)
          if tooltip[1].is_a?(String)
            html_escape(tooltip[1])
          else
            content = translate_from_namespace(:tooltips)
            content.html_safe if content
          end
        else
          content = translate_from_namespace(:tooltips)
          content.html_safe if content
        end
      end

      def tooltip_position
        tooltip = options[:tooltip]
        tooltip.is_a?(Array) ? tooltip[0] : "right"
      end
    end
  end
end

SimpleForm::Inputs::Base.send(:include, SimpleForm::Components::Tooltips)
```

And change the `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` file to include the `use :tooltip` component  after each `use :label`, like so:

```
# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-danger'
  config.button_class = 'btn btn-default'
  config.boolean_label_class = nil

  config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'
    b.use :tooltip,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-muted' }

    b.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'
    b.use :tooltip,  wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-muted' }

    b.use :input
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end
  ... rest of file omitted for brevity...
```

And with a little css to space it correctly:

```
span[data-toggle='tooltip'] {
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

And the javascript that bootstrap requires to activate it:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

It worked great.  I'm using bootstrap 3, rails 5 and simple_form 4.

Answer (score 3):

For bootstrap 5.1, to make this:

[image]

```
<span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="Here's some amazing content.">
  <i class="bi bi-question-circle" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"></i>
</span>
```

And add this to javascript/application.js

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

#### Source

- Adapted from [bootstrap 5.1 docs examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#examples)